# Spark-submit fails to import SparkContext

Tags: python, apache-spark, anaconda, pyspark

I'm running Spark 1.4.1 on my local Mac laptop and am able to use `pyspark` interactively without any issues.  Spark was installed through Homebrew and I'm using Anaconda Python.  However, as soon as I try to use `spark-submit`, I get the following error:

```
15/09/04 08:51:09 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Added file file:test.py does not exist.
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1329)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1305)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$15.apply(SparkContext.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$15.apply(SparkContext.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:234)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:214)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:68)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/09/04 08:51:09 ERROR SparkContext: Error stopping SparkContext after init error.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService.close(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.stop(BlockManager.scala:1216)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.stop(SparkEnv.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1659)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:565)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
 Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:234)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:214)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:68)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 35, in <module> sc = SparkContext("local","test") 
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.4.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 113, in __init__
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.4.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 165, in _do_init
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.4.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 219, in _initialize_context
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.4.1/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 701, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.4.1/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 300, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Added file file:test.py does not exist.
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1329)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1305)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$15.apply(SparkContext.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$15.apply(SparkContext.scala:458)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:234)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:214)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:68)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is my code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext("local","test")
    sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4])
    sc.stop()
```

If I move the file to anywhere in the `/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.4.1/` directory, then `spark-submit` works fine.  I have my environment variables set as follows:

```
export SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.4.1"
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/libexec/python:$SPARK_HOME/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip
```

I'm sure something is set incorrectly in my environment, but I can't seem to track it down.

Comment: Try using `spark-submit <full_path>/text.py`, it looks as if `spark-submit` can't find your Python script.

Comment: I've tried the full path and am still getting the same error.  I've also checked the permissions on the folder and that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: Try adding the directory that holds ´test.py´ to your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Worked great, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The python files that are executed by `spark-submit` should be on the `PYTHONPATH`. Either add the full path of the directory by doing:

```
export PYTHONPATH=full/path/to/dir:$PYTHONPATH
```

or you can also add `'.'` to the `PYTHONPATH` if you are already inside the directory where the python script is

```
export PYTHONPATH='.':$PYTHONPATH
```

Thanks to @Def_Os for pointing that out!